# Swapping Elements in a list

Tags: java, performance, algorithm, programming-challenge

**Challenge**:

> Swap positions in a list

**Specifications**:

> Your program should accept as its first argument a path to a filename.
>   The file contains several test cases, one on each line.
>   Each test case is a list of numbers, supplemented with positions to be swapped.
>   List and positions are separated by a colon.
>   Positions start with 0.
>   There may be more than one position swaps, separated by a comma.
>   Positions swaps are processed left to right.

**Solution**:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SwapElements {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(args[0]));

        while (input.hasNextLine()) {
            String[] temp = input.nextLine().split(":");
            printSwapped(swapList(temp[0], temp[1]));
        }
    }

    public static void printSwapped(List<String> list) {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

        for (String s : list) {
            result.append(' ').append(s);
        }

        System.out.println(result.substring(1));
    }

    public static List<String> swapList(String input, String swapKey) {
        List<String> result = modifyToList(input);

        for (String s : swapKey.split(",")) {
            String[] keys = s.split("-");
            int index1 = Integer.parseInt(keys[0].substring(1));
            int index2 = Integer.parseInt(keys[1]);

            String target1 = result.get(index2);
            String target2 = result.get(index1);

            result.set(index1, target1);
            result.set(index2, target2);
        }

        return result;
    }

    public static List<String> modifyToList(String list) {
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<>(list.length());

        for (String s : list.split("\\s+")) {
            result.add(s);
        }

        return result;
    }   
}
```

**Sample Input**:

> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 : 0-8
>   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 : 0-1, 1-3

**Sample Output**:

> 9 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 1
>   2 4 3 1 5 6 7 8 9 10

It's actually been a while since I did one of these and I get the feeling it shows. The solution itself, of course, works, but I get the sense that it's memory intensive and/or slow. I'd mostly like to focus on optimizing speed, but any and all general feedback is welcome.

What do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switching from a `List<Integer>` to an `int[]` speeds things up quite a bit, for the  input examples you've provided. Note: I've slightly simplified your code to work off a fixed array of strings, merely because it made my testing easier.

```
public class SwapElements {

  private static final String[] lines = { "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 : 0-8",
      "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 : 0-1, 1-3" };

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    for (String line : lines) {
      String[] temp = line.split(":");
      int[] numbers = toPrimitiveArray(temp[0]);
      printSwapped(swapList(numbers, temp[1]));
    }
  }

  private static int[] toPrimitiveArray(String input) {
    String[] numbers = input.split(" ");

    int[] result = new int[numbers.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
      result[i] = Integer.parseInt(numbers[i]);
    }
    return result;
  }

  private static void printSwapped(int[] list) {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i : list) {
      result.append(' ').append(i);
    }

    System.out.println(result.substring(1));
  }

  private static int[] swapList(int[] input, String swapKey) {
    for (String s : swapKey.split(",")) {
      String[] keys = s.split("-");
      int index1 = Integer.parseInt(keys[0].substring(1));
      int index2 = Integer.parseInt(keys[1]);

      int target1 = input[index2];
      int target2 = input[index1];

      input[index1] = target1;
      input[index2] = target2;
    }

    return input;
  }
}
```

Some basic benchmarking showed me that this improved performance from 4,125ns to 2,536ns (almost 40% reduction), for processing both input strings.

Other comments:

- I've  changed most of your `public` methods to `private`, since they don't appear to be used outside of the class.
- Your original code doesn't correctly close the `Scanner` you use. These days, you can avoid that entire problem using NIO classes:

  ```
  List<String> fileLines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(args[0]));
  ```
- You may wish to refactor your code to introduce a `int[] swapElements(String input)` method, so you can unit test more easily.